# How to compare a Series with a Scalar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare a datetime64[ns] pandas Series with a scalar from a different Series, also datetime64[ns], in a loop.

The dataframe:

`ds.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 174764 entries, 0 to 185622
Data columns (total 2 columns):
t1    174764 non-null datetime64[ns]
t2    174764 non-null datetime64[ns]`

The loop:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ds['t3'] = np.zeros(ds.shape[0])
for i in range(ds.shape[0]):
    r_i= ds['t1'].iat[i]
    ds['t3'].iat[i] = ds[(ds.t1.gt(r_1)) & (ds.t2.le(r_i))]['t1'].count()
```

At the moment the duration takes about 8 minutes. I would like to at least half the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert values to numpy arrays and count only `True` values by `np.sum`:

```
t1 = ds['t1'].values
t2 = ds['t2'].values
ds['t3'] = [np.sum((t1 > a) & (t2 < a)) for a, b in zip(t1, t2)]
```

Another idea - need more memory:

```
t11 = t1[:, None]
ds['t3'] = np.sum((t1 > t11) & (t2 < t11), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. The first solution reduces the calculation time from 8 min to 90 secs.

Comment: @René - Supeeeer :)